# Python reports invalid syntax when assigning user defined Kivy widget property

Tags: python, widget, kivy

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp 
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color

Builder.load_string('''
<bbx>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    my2App:
        color: 1,0,0,1

<my2App>:
    text: root.text
    Label:
        text: root.text
        font_size: 16
        size_hint_y: None
        text_size: self.width, None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: root.color
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
''')

class my2App(ScrollView):
    text = StringProperty('default string'*200)
    color = ListProperty([1,0,0,0.25])

class bbx(BoxLayout):
    pass

runTouchApp(bbx())
```

---

This is my practice kivy code. my2App is a user defined widget mostly copied from this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdcUg_rX2fM). The only addition is the color property defined by ListProperty. Somehow this user defined color property didn't work out. I tried to run my2App along and it didn't work either.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):    File "test_anotherviky.py", line
> 38, in <module>
>      ''')    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1796, in load_string
>      parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1185, in
> __init__
>      self.parse(content)    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1291, in parse
>      rule.precompile()    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1049, in
> precompile
>      x.precompile()    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 976, in
> precompile
>      self.co_value = compile(value, self.ctx.filename or '<string>', mode)    File "<string>", line 5
>      color: 1,0,0,1
>           ^  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Answer (score 1):

Widget names must start with an upper case letter to work in kv, as it uses this to distinguish them from properties. Here, it thinks `my2app:` is a property setting.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. But I still cannot set the property value in <Bbx>. Do I have to do this using a method?

Comment: @DaveQ how were you able to set the ListProperty? I am facing issues with code similar to yours, where if I try to set the values in a listproperty of strings from the kv file, the list is actually empty in my widget's instances

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PyCharm 2020.1 and Kivy 1.10.1 and I was having the same problem:
color: 1,0,0,1

> ^  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> But in my case was with: size_hint: None, 1. I fix it using camelcase. Like this:

.py file:
class BoxBlue(BoxLayout):
None

.kv file:
BoxBlue:
size_hint: None,1
width: 30

My class was named: boxBlue, so I changed to BoxBlue in py and kv, and works fine.